# Should I apply pain relieving gel after workout?

Tags: workout

Can I apply pain relieving gel after muscular workout? I would feel much better using such gel and maybe faster to get to comfortable enough to have workout again, but I am wondering if there are difference done to my muscle.

Comment: Care to tell us what the gel is or what may be in it? Its probably just improving the blood flow locally which can feel pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interesting article about overuse of sports cream: http://www.athleteinme.com/ArticleView.aspx?id=712

I think it points to a very simple, but valid point - the continued use of any medication that is not prescribed and supervised by a Dr. has the potential of direct long term harm OR continued masking of the base issue.  If you are under continued and severe enough pain to require continued/overuse of any pain relieving product, it's time to see a Dr. OR modify what you're doing.  Like the punch line to the old joke about 'it hurts when I do this' the response is 'stop doing it'

Comment: That's really horrible!!

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to apply products like [Bio Freeze](http://www.biofreeze.com/) on occasion.  I use it for spot treatment of sore muscles throughout the year.  I would not recommend doing this as part of a daily routine however for two reasons.  First, it shouldn't be necessary.  Second, if you have muscle soreness that often, you are probably doing something else wrong (nutrition, form, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get muscle soreness from a fairly hard workout, but I don't apply any gel or cream  on it as the pain goes away in a couple of days.  But if you're feeling something that's chronic then apply gel then see a doctor.